# Mapping hdfs file to HBase using Oozie

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, oozie

I'm trying to launch a shell job from Oozie where I map files from hdfs to Hbase

The shell script works from command line but not from Oozie

Shell Script:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`/usr/bin/hbase classpath` /usr/bin/hadoop jar /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar importtsv -Dimporttsv.separator=, -Dimporttsv.columns=ORIGINAL:FIELD1,ORIGINAL:FIELD2,ORIGINAL:FIELD3  HBASE_Table /user/U0H8048/file
```

The error is:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/cloudera/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-    1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/cloudera/yarn/nm/filecache/2282/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/cloudera/yarn/nm/filecache/2288/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
  SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:54)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://salcls0226.com:8020/cloudera/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.2.jar
  at    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1128)
  at    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
      ...
```

Does anyone know a possible solution ?

How can I specify that the `hbase-server-0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.2.jar` file is in a local path and not on hdfs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

It needs to add the line `oozie.use.system.libpath=true` *into job.properties* file read by Oozie when a workflow is launched.

You have to add all needed files into HDFS path: */user/oozie/share/lib*. Normally the main library files are already present.